# Twitter Click when you like the shock, how to achieve

Tags: shake

Twitter Click when you like the shock/vibrator, how to achieve,
I only know there is this 
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

Comment: Facebook Click Like will also have

Answer (score 0):

Already .  fixed .

## import

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1519);//1520//1521

Comment: #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>